# Create a MR and MC in a javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, function, memory, calculator

Idealy, I would like my little project to have the memory functions M-, M+, MR and MC. 
I was thinking of separate functions and variables to hold the M- and M+.
Is this a normal approach or there is a better one ?

Any idea what might be wrong with my script ? if there is something wrong ?

the number-display ID is the actual calculator screen

the code is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var display = "";
    var operators = ["/", "*", "-", "+"];
    var decimalAdded = false;

    $("button").click(function() {
        var key = $(this).text();

      //update screen by adding display string to screen with maximum 19 numbers viewable
        function updateDisplay() {
            if (display.length > 19) {
              $("#number-display").html(display.substr(display.length - 19, display.length));
            } else {
              $("#number-display").html(display.substr(0, 19));
            }
        }
      //clear all entries by resetting display and variables
        if (key === "AC" || key === "ON" || key === "MC") {
            decimalAdded = false;
            display = "";
            $("#number-display").html("0");
        }

        else if (key === "OFF") {
            decimalAdded = false;
            display = "";
            $("#number-display").html("");
        }


      //clear previous character and reset decimal bool if last character is decimal
        else if (key === "CE") {
            if (display.substr(display.length - 1, display.length) === ".") {
                decimalAdded = false;
            }
            display = display.substr(0, display.length - 1);
            updateDisplay();
        }

      //add key to display if key is a number
        else if (!isNaN(key)) {
            display += key;
            updateDisplay();
        }
      //check that . is the first in the number before adding and add 0. or just .  
        else if (key === ".") {
            if (!decimalAdded) {
                if(display > 0){
                    display += key;
                }
                else {
                    display += "0" + key;
                }
                decimalAdded = true;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        }
        //if key is basic operator, check that the last input was a number before inputting
        else if (operators.indexOf(key) > -1) {
            decimalAdded = false;
            //first input is a number
            if (display.length > 0 && !isNaN(display.substr(display.length - 1, display.length))) {
                display += key;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        // allow minus sign as first input
            else if (display.length === 0 && key === "-") {
                display += key;
                updateDisplay();
            }

        }
        // calculate square root of number

        else if ( $(this).id === "sqrt") {

                var tempStore = display.html();
                $("#number-display").html(eval(Math.sqrt(tempStore)));
                decimalAdded = false;
        }

        // change sign of number

        else if ($(this).id === "plusmn") {
            var newNum = display * -1;
            $("#number-display").html(newNum);
        }

        // create memory plus and minus and calculate MR
        else if (key === "M-") {

        }
        else if (key === "M+") {

        }

        // percentage function

        else if (key === "%"){

        }

        else if (key == "=") {
            //if last input is a decimal or operator, remove from display
            if (isNaN(display.substr(display.length - 1, display.length))) {
                display = display.substr(0, display.length - 1);
            }
            var calc = display;
            calc = eval(calc);
            display = String(calc);
            if (display.indexOf('.')) {
                decimalAdded = true;
            } else {
                decimalAdded = false;
            }
            $("#number-display").html(display);
        }
    });});
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is a `switch` statement, which would look something like:

```
switch (key) {
  case "M-":
    // do stuff
    break;
  case "M+":
    // do stuff
    break;
  case "%":
    // do stuff
    break;
  case "=":
    // do stuff
    break;
}
```

More documentation on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will look into this. Its kind of if/else type of result isn't it ? If I add variables for M= and M- and create a function for & then its basically solved :P

Comment: Yeah it's like if/else, except it's more readable and you can easily add more cases.